# Плавное перемещение карточек при удалении одной из них

Tags: css, css-animation

Имеются карточки, которые при помощи display: flex идут в ряд. Каждая карточка по клику на ней удаляется из DOM. При удалении карточки остальные перестраиваются из-за появившегося свободного места. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы карточки при удалении одной из них перестраивались не рывком, а плавно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const cards = document.querySelector(".cards");

const handler = function() {
  this.classList.add("hide");
  let target = this,
    parent = target.parentNode,
    targetRect = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
    children = parent.lastElementChild;
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (children === target) {
      parent.removeChild(target)
    } else {
      while (true) {

        if (children === target) {
          parent.removeChild(target);
          break;
        }

        let rect = children.getBoundingClientRect(),
          current = children,
          prevRect = [];

        children = children.previousElementSibling;

        if (!children) {
          break
        }

        if (children === target) {
          prevRect = targetRect;
        } else {
          prevRect = children.getBoundingClientRect()
        }

        let x = rect.x - prevRect.x;
        if (x < 0) {
          let temp = children.previousElementSibling;
          if (temp) {
            tempRect = temp.getBoundingClientRect();
            x = prevRect.x - tempRect.x;
          } else {
            x = prevRect.width
          }
        }

        current.style.transition = "none";
        current.style.transform = "translateX(" + x + "px)";

        setTimeout(() => {
          current.style.transition = "";
          current.style.transform = "";
        }, 50);
      }
    }
  }, 150);
};

[].forEach.call(cards.children, card => {
  card.addEventListener("click", handler);
})
```

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.cards-child {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  transition-property: transform opacity;
  transition-duration: .4s;
}

.cards-child:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.cards-child:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}

.cards-child:active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

.cards-child.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="1"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="2"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="3"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="4"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="5"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="6"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="7"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="8"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="9"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="10"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="11"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="12"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="13"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="14"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="15"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="16"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="17"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="18"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="19"></div>
  <div class="cards-child" data-content="20"></div>
</div>
```